# Hive query to multiple db same table

Tags: hive

Lets say have multiple databases on hive, a table with same name exists in all the databases, is there a way to give wild characters ? for e.g in under ab1, ab2, ab3 databases a tables "t1" exists in all the 3 databases. can i run a extract query to get data from all the tables under all databases ?

I tried `select * from ab*.t1;` gives me an error

Comment: Use `union` and specify full database name.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do with HIVE query!

Unless you want to do some scripting around.
You can use `show databases like 'ab*'` to retrieve list of databases and then manually build query, where you list all databases/tables.